# Order of Multi-class Predictions in keras

Tags: python-3.x, keras

I've trained a multi-label (2), multi-class (3) model with keras and model.predict(test_data) gives 3 (num_samples, 1) ndarray's ... so far so good but how can I check which prediction array is for which class: 
My model architecture is:

```
Input - Embedding - GRU1 - BatchNorm - Dropout - GRU2 - Dense(1) for Class1 - Dense(1) for Class2 - Dense(1) for Class3
```

Keras [docs](https://keras.io/models/model/) mention only that predict() returns 'Numpy array(s) of predictions' but nothing about order being maintained. Thanks,

Comment: The order is the same you use when you define your model.

Comment: You could well be right but can you provide some reference/intuition?

Comment: Try different output shapes in each output to confirm. Example: Dense(1), Dense(2) and Dense(3)

Comment: Number of ndarrays returned by predict() == number of final layer neurons summed across final Dense() layers, but that still says nothing about their order. My hunch is that you're right but still it seems like a loose end as of now

Comment: No, number of ndarrays returned by predict == 3 (one for each layer), one will have shape (batch,1), the other (batch,2) and the last (batch,3).